# How to fix Javascript no longer working after converting to core 2.2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I convert an application from Core 1.1 to 2.2.  Now some of my JS is not working

After conversion I noticed that my  columns were no longer sorting when I clicked on them.  I added some JS code and now it works.  This is when I found that there was a custom JS lib with the sorting code in there but it no longer worked.
I also found that the filtering (client side) is not working.

I converted the code following the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Here is the JS script to perform the filtering.

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.appgrid = function appgrid() {
function configureFilter() {
            $("[data-update-departments]").on("change", function () {
                var triggerControl = $(this);
                var connectedControl = $(triggerControl.data("update-departments"));

                if (!connectedControl.data("default")) {
                    connectedControl.data("default", connectedControl.children());
                }
                var triggerValue = triggerControl.find(":selected").val();

                if (triggerValue) {
                    $.getJSON("/ManageNomination/GetDepartments?company=" + triggerValue, function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            connectedControl.children().remove();
                            connectedControl.append('<option value=""></option>');
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                connectedControl.append('<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>');
                            }
                            connectedControl.removeAttr("disabled");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    connectedControl.children().remove();
                    connectedControl.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            })

            $("#applyFilter").on("click", function () {
                filter = $.extend({}, defaultFilter);
                $("[id^=filter-]").each(function () {
                    var control = $(this);
                    var controlId = control.attr("id").substr(7);
                    if (this.type === "text" || this.type === "date") {
                        filter[controlId] = control.val();
                    } else if (this.type === "select-one") {
                        filter[controlId] = control.find(":selected").val();
                    }
                });

                localStorage.setItem('filter', JSON.stringify(filter));

                refreshData();
                $("#filter-applied-message").show();
            });

            $(".clearFilter").on("click", function () {
                filter = $.extend({}, defaultFilter);
                localStorage.removeItem('filter');
                localStorage.removeItem('currentPage');
                refreshData();
                $("#filter-applied-message").hide();
                setFilterControlValues();
            });

            setFilterControlValues();
        }

        function setFilterControlValues() {
            // repopulate the filter fields with the saved filter values
            $("[id^=filter-]").each(function () {
                var control = $(this);
                var controlId = control.attr("id").substr(7);
                control.val(filter[controlId] || defaultFilter[controlId] || "");

                if (this.type === "select-one" && control.data("update-departments")) {
                    if (control.find(":selected").val()) {
                        // control is a connected dropdown and has a selected value
                        $(control.data("update-departments")).removeAttr("disabled");
                    } else {
                        $(control.data("update-departments")).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                }

                // open the filter panel automatically
                //$(".filterPanel").collapse("show");
            });
        }
```

So the dropdowns for the filtering are populated but when I select a value to filter on, nothing happens.

TIA

HaYen

Comment: Did you lose your refs to jquery or something? This is a really broad one to diagnose.

Comment: Is there any error in the web browser debug tool console tab?

Comment: Fixed it!!! it had nothing to do with conversion from FW to Core just my typo.  Thank you both very much!!!